# Line drawing animation with pure css

Tags: css, animation

Is there any way to implement a CSS animation in which a dot grows to be a line?

```
point l (a dot) ---------------------------> point m (a line)
```

I know this can be done with SVG, but I want to know if it is possible to be implemented with pure CSS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the `transition` property in CSS, you can give drawing effect to a `<div>` by targeting its `width` property.

Hover over the **orange** color dot on result screen.

```css
.point {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background: tomato;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: width 1s ease;
}

.point:hover {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="point"></div>
```

Comment: Imho you should give it a border-radius: 3px; otherwise the "It's not a dot" comment will come.

Answer (score 20):

You could use a border on an element with 1px which grows to the required length.

Using `@keyframes` and `animation` properties you can get this to start from page load.

```css
div{
  height:0px;
  width:1px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
  
  -webkit-animation: increase 3s;
  -moz-animation:    increase 3s; 
  -o-animation:      increase 3s; 
  animation:         increase 3s; 
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes increase {
    100% {
        width: 300px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: How would you draw a vertical line?